# Форма в Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony, php

Проблема с обработкой формы модуля Company, в CompaniaForm

```
$this->widgetSchema['locality_id'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
        'choices' => $location['locality'],
        'multiple'=> FALSE,
        'expanded'=> FALSE,
        'default' => $location['locality']
    ));
```

При экшене Edit все работает, как мне нужно т.е. отображается в списке текущее значение для записи. НО при вызове экшена NEW этот список остается незаполненым вообще! Да, все логично работает, но как решить возникший вопрос? Как прописать правила вывода этого элемента формы специально для экшена NEW?

Answer (score 1):

Все решается методом `$this->isNew();`.